# Data visualization of different measures with different domains on a map

Tags: d3.js, colors, data-visualization

I have a map of Europe divided by countries and different measures to be represented using a choropletic map.
Based on the selected radio button, the map is colored according to the values ​​in the csv file.

Here is the code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./map.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
   <div id="map-container"></div>

   <div id="radio-container">
      <form id="radio-selector">
         <input type="radio" name="radio-selector" id="rb1" value="m1" checked />
         <label for="rb1">Measure 1</label>
         <br>
         <input type="radio" name="radio-selector" id="rb1" value="m2" />
         <label for="rb2">Measure 2</label>
         <br>
         <input type="radio" name="radio-selector" id="rb1" value="m3" />
         <label for="rb3">Measure 3</label>
      </form>
   </div>

   <script src="./map.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**map.js**

```
var csvValue = [];

var projection = d3.geoMercator()
   .scale(500)
   .translate([200, 700])

var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

var width = 700;
var height = 400;

var svg = d3.select("#map-container").append("svg")
   .attr("id", "container-map-svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);

// to color countries
var colors = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, 100]) 
   .range(["#131313", "#ba3c28"]); 

var measSelected = document.querySelector('input[name=radio-selector]:checked').value;


var pathToNuts0 = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rveciana/5919944/raw/2fef6be25d39ebeb3bead3933b2c9380497ddff4/nuts0.json';

d3.queue()
   .defer(d3.json, pathToNuts0)
   .defer(d3.csv, './data.csv')
   .await(makeMap); 

function makeMap(error, nuts0, data) {
   if (error) {
      console.log("*** ERROR LOADING FILES: " + error + " ***");
      throw error;
   }

   csvValue = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
         return d.MEASURE;
      })
      .object(data);

   var country = topojson.feature(nuts0, nuts0.objects.nuts0);

   // create map
   svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(country.features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "country")
      .attr("id", function(d) {
         return "country" + d.properties.nuts_id;
      })
      .attr("d", path);

   colorCountries();
}

function colorCountries() {
   svg.selectAll("path")
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
         var col = +getColor(d.properties.nuts_id);
         return colors(col); 
      });
}

var getColor = function(nutsId) {
   measSelected = document.querySelector('input[name=radio-selector]:checked').value;
   var complete = csvValue[measSelected].slice();
   var selectedValue = complete.find(function(tupla) {
      return tupla.ID_NUT == nutsId;
   });
   if (selectedValue == null) {
      return -1;
   } 
   else {
      var value = selectedValue.VALUE;
      return value;
   }
}


function measures() {
    var measSelected = document.querySelector('input[name="radio-selector"]:checked').value; 
}

var updateRadio = function() {
    measSelected = $('input[name=radio-selector]:checked', '#desses').val(); 
    colorCountries(); 
    measures();
}
$("#radio-selector").on("change", updateRadio);
```

**data.csv**

```
ID_NUT,MEASURE,VALUE
AT,m1,97.1
AT,m2,74
AT,m3,28.53
BE,m1,98
BE,m2,97.1
BE,m3,8
BG,m1,94.5
BG,m2,56
BG,m3,38.42
CY,m1,99.32
CY,m2,91
CY,m3,23.42
CZ,m1,98.5
CZ,m2,4
CZ,m3,64.51
DE,m1,97
DE,m2,2
DE,m3,78.77
DK,m1,96.8
DK,m2,95
DK,m3,86.95
EE,m1,95.8
EE,m2,79
EE,m3,84.10
EL,m1,96.4
EL,m2,68
EL,m3,42.78
ES,m1,93.9
ES,m2,69
ES,m3,95.4
FI,m1,97.8
FI,m2,36
FI,m3,98.65
FR,m1,97.9
FR,m2,74
FR,m3,99.75
HR,m1,99.1
HR,m2,39
HR,m3,63.78
HU,m1,96.12
HU,m2,84
HU,m3,81
IE,m1,98.55
IE,m2,89
IE,m3,69.4
IT,m1,99.65
IT,m2,40
IT,m3,75.93
LT,m1,97.45
LT,m2,56
LT,m3,93.67
LU,m1,97.63
LU,m2,19
LU,m3,31.48
LV,m1,95.24
LV,m2,71
LV,m3,39
MT,m1,96.52
MT,m2,85
MT,m3,93
NL,m1,98
NL,m2,39
NL,m3,88.88
PL,m1,99.10
PL,m2,77
PL,m3,15
PT,m1,94.15
PT,m2,95
PT,m3,15
RO,m1,97
RO,m2,71
RO,m3,74
SE,m1,89.4
SE,m2,92
SE,m3,69.64
SI,m1,97.86
SI,m2,52
SI,m3,74.78
SK,m1,98
SK,m2,85
SK,m3,88
UK,m1,99.4
UK,m2,100
UK,m3,97
```

The code is correct, it works and doesn't generate errors.
The problem I would like to solve is the color question.

In csv file, all values ​​are in the range `[0, 100]` because they represent percentages.
As seen in the csv, the values ​​corresponding to `m1` are very high values ​​`(>=90)` while those referring to `m2` and `m3` vary a lot.
If I use only one color scale (as written in the code) whose domain is `[0, 100]`, the coropletic map ridden to `m1` is not very significant.
How can I solve this problem?

What I would like to do is use a single color scale for all three measurements but make sure that the differences, even the smallest, between the values ​​are visible.

My question is more theory than practice. I don't care about the code, if there is better.
I would really like an idea-level solution, how can I deal with and solve this problem?

Thanks

> Question off-topic: how do I use a snippet stack in this case? How can I add an external file (data.csv)?

### ----------

I modified my code like this:

```
var colors = d3.scaleQuantile()
   .domain([0, 100]) 
   .range(["#131313", "#241715", "#341b17", "#451f19", "#56231b", "#67281e", "#772c20", "#883022", "#993424", "#a93826", "#ba3c28"]);
```

Unfortunately I didn't get any visual result (or even errors).
With both `scaleLinear()` and `scaleQuantile()` the result is this:
[image]

Other question. Using this technique (which if I understand correctly fits according to the data domain) would I have different legends for each measure?

---

My data are in this form:

```
ID,COUNTRY,YEAR,A,B,C
AL,Albania,2000,98,50,10
AL,Albania,2001,41,2,14
AL,Albania,2002,75,51,10
DE,Germany,2000,74,21,25
DE,Germany,2001,46,2,48
DE,Germany,2002,74,81,90
...
```

So I don't have a simple array like `var data = [..., ...]`.

Comment: Do you think selecting different colors for `m1, m2, m3` and gradients (darker for higher value and lighter for smaller values) within those colors would make sense?

Comment: @Shashank Thanks for your advice. I already use the gradients. I would prefer to use the same color because in this example I have only 3 measures, but in reality I have a dozen.
And, if I understand what you mean, using different colors would not solve the problem.

Comment: @vila regarding your off-topic question: you can't. One solution is using template literals to hardcode your CSV.

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions for your problem. However, the *"correct"* solution in this case is using the adequate scale.

Before talking about that adequate scale, let's look at your problem closely and discuss some continuous scale approaches.

#### Your problem

As you explained in the question, the problem is that your data is heavily skewed towards one end of the domain.

To visualize it, I created this simple dataset...

```
var data = [2, 30, 60, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99];
```

... going from `0` to `100`, but *"skewed to the right"*.

Given your colours, this is the result of the use of a simple linear scale:

```js
var data = [0, 30, 60, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 100];
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range(["#131313", "#ba3c28"])
var div = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d => scale(d))
```

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As you know, we cannot easily see the differences for most of the values.

You could try to make your domain skewed as well. For instance, using a power scale with a high exponent:

```js
var data = [0, 30, 60, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 100];
var scale = d3.scalePow()
  .exponent(10)
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range(["#131313", "#ba3c28"])
var div = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d => scale(d))
```

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

The problem of this approach is that it will be a game of trial and error, until you get the right exponent, which will be different for each data set...

So, let's drop the continuous scale and use the *"correct"* scale:

#### The quantile scale

Instead of a continuous scale, the best scale to see the differences in your population is a quantile scale. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#quantile-scales):

> Quantile scales map a sampled input domain to a discrete range. The domain is considered continuous and thus the scale will accept any reasonable input value; however, the domain is specified as a discrete set of sample values. The number of values in (the cardinality of) the output range determines the number of quantiles that will be computed from the domain. To compute the quantiles, **the domain is sorted, and treated as a population of discrete values**. (emphasis mine)

So, the first step is creating the range array. Let's create an array of 10 colours. Based on your colours, it will be:

```
["#131313", "#241715", "#341b17", "#451f19", "#56231b", "#67281e", "#772c20", "#883022", "#993424", "#a93826", "#ba3c28"]
```

Then, using that range, we create our quantile scale:

```
var scale = d3.scaleQuantile()
  .domain(data)
  .range(["#131313", "#241715", "#341b17", "#451f19", "#56231b", "#67281e", "#772c20", "#883022", "#993424", "#a93826", "#ba3c28"])
```

This is the demo:

```js
var data = [0, 30, 60, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 100];
var scale = d3.scaleQuantile()
  .domain(data)
  .range(["#131313", "#241715", "#341b17", "#451f19", "#56231b", "#67281e", "#772c20", "#883022", "#993424", "#a93826", "#ba3c28"])
var div = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d => scale(d));
```

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have modified the main message with some details/problems. Could you help me?

Comment: Please, don't edit your question to make further questions. I answered your original question here. If you have further issues, post them as *new* questions.

Comment: I don't think it's a new question. The problem is always that.

Comment: Ok, if you think so, I reverted the rollback, so now you have your question edited. I hope someone else can help you.

Comment: I would like to use the quantile scale but my data has this form: `ID,COUNTRY,YEAR,A,B,C
AL,Albania,2000,98,50,10
AL,Albania,2001,41,2,14
AL,Albania,2002,75,51,10
DE,Germany,2000,74,21,25
DE,Germany,2001,46,2,48
DE,Germany,2002,74,81,90
....`
How can I adapt the code?

Comment: Well, as I said before, I hope someone else can help you regarding this issue.