# Using scaleQuantile with "viridis" color scheme

Tags: d3.js, colors, quantile

I have data whose values have a range (0, 100) but most of them have values ranging between 80 and 100.

Example of data: `97.00 93.30 92.20 92.70 91.10 89.10 89.90 89.10 89.70 88.90 
89.00 89.30 88.76 88.46 87.45 85.05`

I have to do a visualization using colors and using a linear scale is not the best because it does not allow me to distinguish colors quite easily.
So I thought about using a `scaleQuantile`.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023990/data-visualization-of-different-measures-with-different-domains-on-a-map) that uses colors from black to red but I would like to use the Viridis scale.
How can I do that?

This is my piece of code:

```
var colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile(d3.interpolateViridis)
    .domain([0, 100]);

// other code

var cells = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('g').append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'cell')
    .attr('width', cellSize)
    .attr('height', cellSize)
    .attr("rx", 4)
   .attr("ry", 4)
    .attr('y', function(d) { 
        return yScale(d.nuts_name); 
    })
    .attr('x', function(d) { 
        return xScale(d.year); 
    })
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
        return colorScale(d.value);
        }
    })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems here:

1. The domain in a quantile scale, unlike a quantize scale, is not a range between two values. It has to be the array with all the values. The API is clear about that:

   > If domain is specified, sets the domain of the quantile scale to the specified set of **discrete numeric values**. (emphasis mine)
2. That's not the correct way to use `d3.interpolateViridis`. Again, the API is clear:

   > Given a number t in the range [0,1], returns the corresponding color from the “viridis” perceptually-uniform color scheme

So, a simple solution is creating the quantile scale in such a way that it returns a number from `0` to `1` according to your data array (here, I'm creating 10 bins):

```
var colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
  .domain(data)
  .range(d3.range(0, 1.1, 0.1));
```

And then pass that value to `d3.interpolateViridis`:

```
d3.interpolateViridis(colorScale(d))
```

Here is a demo. The first row of `<divs>` use the data as they are, the second one uses a sorted array:

```js
var data = [97.00, 93.30, 92.20, 92.70, 91.10, 89.10, 89.90, 89.10, 89.70, 88.90, 89.00, 89.30, 88.76, 88.46, 87.45, 85.05];

var sortedData = data.concat().sort();

var colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
  .domain(data)
  .range(d3.range(0, 1.1, 0.1));

var divs = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "cell")
  .style("background-color", function(d) {
    return d3.interpolateViridis(colorScale(d))
  });

d3.select("body").append("div")
  .style("height", "40px")

var div2 = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(sortedData)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "cell")
  .style("background-color", function(d) {
    return d3.interpolateViridis(colorScale(d))
  });
```

```css
.cell {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply. The problem is that I have I can't create a data array like in this simple example. My data are more complex, I have a data array for each country of the world.. So, what can I do?

Comment: Well, I wrote an answer based on the data you provided in the question. If your data is different, I suggest you to post a new question regarding that (please, do not edit this one). However, based on your description, I'd say that you can simply concat all the values, creating a huge array with all discrete numeric values.